# AceGen set up for Linux

Tags: acegen

I would like to run Abaqus User Element (UEL) subroutine generated by AceGen. I have Abaqus 6.14 coupled with gfortran compiler in Linux Ubuntu operating system. How do I configure ABAQUSCompile.bat ,abaqus_v6.env and ABAQUSRun.bat files ?